# Sorry, something went wrong. in facebook login with paspport node js

Tags: node.js, facebook-authentication

and im getting this error
https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&client_id=247701708059343

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g7lD.png)

**this is paspport.use
**passport.use(
new FacebookStrategy(
{
clientID: '------------------',
clientSecret: '--------------------------',
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback',
profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name','photos'], // Specify the required profile fields
},
(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
handleLoginCallback(LoginType.Facebook, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done);
}
)
);

**this is my router
**router.get('/facebook', facebookLogin);

router.get('/facebook/callback', facebookCallback)

**this is my call back and the login
**export const facebookLogin = passport.authenticate('facebook', {
scope: ['public_profile', 'email'],
session: false,
});

export const facebookCallback = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
passport.authenticate('facebook', (err: any, result: any) => {
if (err) {
return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred during facebook login.' });
}

```
if (!result) {
  return res.status(401).json({ error: 'facebook authentication failed.' });
}

// Send the token in the response headers
res.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${result.token}`);
return res.status(200).json({ user: result.user, token: result.token }); // You can also send the user data in the response if needed.
```

})(req, res, next);
};